# Reg ex assistance

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the following with regex and something is off:

```
\/wp-content\/uploads\/(.[0-9]*)\/(.[0-9]*)\/(.*) \/$3
```

I'm looking to match `(domain.com/wp-content/uploads/05/2020/image.jpg)`

As an example. The goal is to do a 301 redirect to `domain.com/image.jpg`but I need to do this for any URL that has a month and year

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

`(\S+)\/wp-content\/uploads\/(?:0\d|1[0-2])\/\d{4}\/(\S+)`

then replace with `$1/$2`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRhpBg/6)

Since the URL cannot contain space characters, it is better to use `\S` to avoid their presence. Also, month's value should be validated as shown. A similar thing needs to be done for year's value if you know the range of valid values for the same.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
\((.*)\/wp-content\/uploads\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\/(.*)\)
```

`$1/$2` will give you `domain.com/image.jpg`

---

if you want to validate also month and year, go on:

```
\((.*)\/wp-content\/uploads\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})\/(.*)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VTUDmM/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
/domain.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\/.*/i
```

This will match the following:

- domain.com/wp-content/uploads/05/2020/image.jpg
- domain.com/wp-content/uploads/05/2020/other.jpg

and not match:

- domain.com/wp-content/uploads/05/20/image.jpg
- domain.com/wp-content/uploads/0500/2020/image.jpg

You can test in on [regexr](https://regexr.com/54lrb).